# How do I use the medic's shield on Mann vs Machine?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine, tf2-medic

For a while now I have been playing Mann vs Machine on TF2. I see everybody using these large shields as Medic, which I can also see in the upgrade menu.

So I was wondering, how do I activate this shield with the default keys?

If it helps any I play on PC.

Answer (score 8):

The default control is Mouse3. This is your middle mouse button- clicking the mousewheel.

If you want to change the control, it is listed as Special Attack on the controls menu.

Comment: @AndrewEckert No problem. If my answer helped you, accept it by clicking the tick button below the voting arrows; we'll both get reputation for it.