# How do I activate my canteen Ubercharge?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I'd like some help with the Mann vs. Machine controls. Thanks to Studoku I now know how to [activate my Shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225492/how-do-i-use-the-medics-shield-on-mann-vs-machine?rq=1) as a Medic, but how do I activate my power-up canteen for the extra Ubercharge?

Comment: Partial duplicate of [How do I use the medic's shield on Mann vs Machine?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225492/how-do-i-use-the-medics-shield-on-mann-vs-machine?rq=1)

Comment: @Studoku, oh thanks. I'll edit the post now that I only need the canteen button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canteen is equipped in the action slot, the same slot used for Spellbooks and the [Dueling Mini-game](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dueling_Mini-Game).

Then you should be able to use the canteen once it is filled by using the <kbd>H</kbd> key. Which is the action key.

Pending your button layout it could also be the <kbd>G</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks Winter! Now I can be the best most professional Boot Camp Medic ever...

Comment: Hoo-rah soldier!

Comment: Taunts are in their own menu these days.  The action slot is also used for Spellbooks and the [Dueling Mini-game](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dueling_Mini-Game).